# Genealogytree export to SVG file

Tags: svg, genealogytree, extract

I have a simple family tree defined in Latex and package genealogytree:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=formal graph]{child[id=fam_A]{g[id=na1,male]{a_1}p[id=na2,female]{a_2}child[id=fam_B]{p[id=nb1,male]{b_1}g[id=na3,female]{a_3}c[id=nb2,male]{b_2}c[id=nb3,female]{b_3}}child[id=fam_C]{g[id=na4,male]{a_4}p[id=nc1,female]{c_1}c[id=nc2,male]{c_2}union[id=fam_D]{p[id=nd1,female]{d_1}c[id=nd2,female]{d_2}c[id=nd3,male]{d_3}c[id=nd4,male]{d_4}}}c[id=na5,female]{a_5}}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I can generate PDF using commandline:

```
pdflatex myFile.tex
```

But I would like to have result as SVG file.
How can I extract it to SVG file (not SVG inside PDF)?

Thank you for help !

Comment: I use command: "latex myFile.tex" and then "dvisvgm myFile.dvi". The result is: only some fonts prints - not the image that I can see in the pdf file. 
(I use Mac, but it should not be the case, yes?)

Comment: I did the same on linux machine: "latex myFile.tex" and then "dvisvgm myFile.dvi" and  confirm that it works! it exported content to svg file, thank you very much for help !

Answer (score 0):

Run "latex myFile.tex" and then "dvisvgm myFile.dvi".
For me worked on Linux, I got some problems on Mac.